# WFS query against SQL Server - Returned results not restricted by query

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wfs, sql-server, filter

I have an **SQL Server 2012 table**, which contains a DbGeometry column with a spatial index.  Then a **Geoserver 2.7** using it.  The problem is that when I do a **WFS query** it doesn't restrict the results to the coordinates I pass in by **BBOX**, it always returns all records.

I create the database entry using:

```
DbGeometry geo = DbGeometry.PointFromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", hp.Lng, hp.Lat), 4326);
```

The point inserts fine, using 4326 & Long/Lat.  Geoserver sees it and picks up Native & Declared SRS of EPSG:4326.  I have tried 'Force declared' and 'Keep native'.

Ultimately I'm using Leaflet map with the WFS query as an Ajax call, but for now I'm just trying to get this working using a browser call.

The call/query looks like this:
http://ourserver:port/geoserver/ncc/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typename=ncc:OurLayer&srsName=EPSG:4326&bbox=-0.843632,53.035893,-0.755842,53.077641,EPSG:4326

Is there anything else I can try to fix this problem or even any other way of doing the same thing?

I have seen some posts about SQL Server sometimes passing back inaccurate results, but this isn't restricting them *at all*.

Edit to include this, the returned data.

```
<ncc:Location>
    <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
        <gml:pos>-1.11036761969209 53.3084063531532</gml:pos>
    </gml:Point>
</ncc:Location>
```

**UPDATE:** Interestingly, if we try clearing and repopulating the data and recreate a layer using EPSG:27700, the bounding box query works using easting/northing. On the same column.

**Temporary workaround solution:** Disabling the Spatial Index within SQL Server seems to rectify the issue.  Presumably it is then forced to use the property rather than the index.  However this is obviously not ideal.

Comment: for WFS 2.0 you need to specify EPSG:4326 points as lat/lon not lon/lat so that may be the issue - see http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html for more info

Comment: But if the axis order is wrong then the BBOX is probably somewhere else than the data and query should find nothing, not everything like in this case.

Comment: When I disable the Spatial Index in SQL Server, the issue disappears.